# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named ""

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

i have the following directory structure.

```
program/
    src/
        main/
             python/
                   file1.py
                   file2.py
        test/
             python/
                   file3.py
```

file2.py has a import statement where file1 is a function in file1

```
from file1 import file1
```

file3.py has an import statement

```
from src.main.python.file2 import *
```

when i run pytest scr/test, compiler throws error

```
from file1 import file1    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'
```

the root directory when running this from git bash is program. Also i cannot change the relative import of file2.py since file1 and file2 are copied to docker image.

How can i do a workaround to solve this ?

Comment: Check sys.path what it is showing. It is a good practice to mention function name instead of * while importing. from src.main.python.file2 import *

Comment: sys.path prints path to the root "program"